# Save a JSON response to use for debugging purposes

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I'm basically trying to find a way to save a JSON server response, so can work on some app logic that relies on the response even when the server is no longer returning it. When I get the data back, I can print it out and it will look something like this:

```
<7b202254 7269704c 69737422 3a207b22 43757272 656e7454 696d6522 3a203134 30353037 33323836 ...
```

Is there any way I can create an instance of NSData using this information (NSData dataWithData?)? Or is there a way to create JSON dict/array with the JSON string?

TL;DR how do I save a JSON server response and add a debug option to fake the server response?

Comment: why don't you save in a txt file and add it to your resource folder??

Comment: How would I turn the text back into an array/dict containing the JSON?

Comment: @user3490319 Check my answer for how you would retrieve json as array or, dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly save the `jsonData` `(NSData)` into a file, and use it, see below

```
{
    //Write NSData directly to file
    [jsonData writeToFile:[self jsonFilePath] atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

    //Read from file
    NSJSONSerialization *json=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[self jsonFilePath]] options:0 error:nil];

    //The json object can be used as an Array or, Dictionary
    NSArray *array=(NSArray *)json;
    //OR
    NSDictionary *dic=(NSDictionary *)json;

}

-(NSString *)jsonFilePath{

   return [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"file.json"];
}
```

Hope it helps.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You Json Response data is image data . You can store it in document directory as below.

```
        NSData *webData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image1, 0.5);

        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

        NSString *savedImagePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Profile1.jpeg"];

        [webData writeToFile:savedImagePath atomically:YES];
```

Now in your Document Directory store image. check go to  Iphone Simulator > Application > ProjectName > Documents

Answer (score 0):

Store JSON in text file, as suggested by other.

Now where you want to fetch this text file data, you can use -

```
NSString *jsonFilepath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"jsonFile" ofType:@"text"];
// JSON Data
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile: jsonFilepath];

// JSON String
NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:jsonFilepath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
```

Now you can perform all operation with JSON, as you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can save your JSON Data as a plist in your App's Document Folder..

```
-(void)SaveResponse
{

NSError *error = nil;

        NSData *JSONData = Your Current Data that received from server

        NSMutableDictionary *objDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization
                                                  JSONObjectWithData:JSONData
                                                  options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments
                                                  error:&error];

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];


     NSString *strFilePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Response.plist"];

     [objDictionary writeToFile:strFilePath atomically:YES];

}
```